# Fast Realtime Reverb

Tags: reverb

I am trying to implement a reverb algorithm but my knowledge is extremely limited in DSP. I am making a music application and I need to be able to process Float PCMs with a reverb algorithm to enable audio FX. Is there a fast, real-time reverb algorithm that anyone can suggest me? Any link, article etc would be appreciated. I just do not know where to start.

Comment: Are you asking for a ready-to-use implementation or a description of the algorithm, e.g., in an article? If you're asking for an implementation, could you specify the language you're using? (I'm just asking because you mentioned that your DSP knowledge is limited.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the classic reverb algorithms that are publicly available is    [Freeverb](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/06/freeverb-original-public-domain-code-by.html). It is based on a [Schroeder reverberation algorithm](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/pasp/Schroeder_Reverberators.html) (see ,e.g., [1]) which I expect to have comparatively low CPU consumption.

---

[1] M. R. Schroeder and B. F. Logan, "Colorless Artificial Reverberation" IRE Transactions on Audio, vol. AU-9, pp. 209-214, Nov.-Dec. 1961. http://www2.ece.rochester.edu/courses/ECE472/resources/Papers/Schroeder_1961.pdf

Answer (score 2):

One more: https://github.com/highfidelity/gverb Sounds also a lot better than the Schroeder Reverb.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach is

[https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/EffectDesignPart1.pdf](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Edattorro/EffectDesignPart1.pdf)

Sounds a lot better than the Schroder algorithms.